# Time series model for life insurance claims

Tags: time-series, model

I want to come up with a time series model that will enable me to forecast the number of life insurance claims. I have collected the data (number of claims) from January 2013 to December 2016.

My question is what model can best suit my data and how best can I set up the model.

The plot is as below
[image]

Comment: Step 1) Plot the data. Step 2) Show us the plot.

Comment: I think cost of the claims is what should be plotted.

Comment: Thanks very much for the responses @Carl. i will show you the plot for the number of claims, i've done it on excell.

Comment: Thank you @Michael,,yes the cost of the claims is what i should be more interested on, i will collect the data. but first i wanted to know of i can come up with a model that can forecast the number of claims.

Comment: I suggest (strongly) that you post the actual data